# how to queue a command to run after another command finishes?

Tags: command-line, scheduling

Sometimes I start a program that takes a very long time to finish (`emerge`), then realize that I should go to bed instead of waiting for it. If I know this in the first place I would run

```
program; halt
```

However, now that I have started the program already, how can I "schedule" the computer to shutdown when that process finishes? Would `Ctrl+z` then `fg; halt` be OK?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, that would work.

If unsure, you may test it with

- `sleep 15`
- <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd>
- `fg; echo "it works"`

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to just type `halt` in your terminal while the first command is running; as long as the first command doesn't read input at some point it will sit in the terminal's buffer and the shell will read it when the first program ends

Answer (score 1):

Using the `wait` command

```
$ sleep 10 &
[1] 29703
$ wait 29703 && echo hello
[1]+  Done                    sleep 10
hello
```